# CSS selector for attribute names based on a wildcard

Tags: css, css-selectors, attributes

I've recently been doing a little studying on CSS selectors and have run into a question regarding the new "data-*" attributes.

I understand that in order to select elements with a data attribute there are a few ways of going about it:

```
[data-something='value']{...}    // data-something has value = 'value'
[data-something^='value']{...}   // data-something has value that STARTS with 'value'
[data-something*='value']{...}   // data-something has value with 'value SOMEWHERE in it
```

There are other variations of these, but my question pertains to CSS selectors that can target elements that simply HAVE a "data" attribute. More specifically, is there a CSS selector that can target elements that have ANY "data" attribute at all?

While incorrect, I'm thinking of something like:

```
[data]{...}
```

I've been searching through Google but haven't found anything regarding a generic selector for the attribute yet.

Comment: It would be cool if you could do something like `[data-*]`..

Comment: Are you using vanilla CSS or are you using some kind of pre-compiler like LESS, Stylus, etc...?

Comment: I figured there would be a way of imitating this behavior in SASS or LESS, but I've only been looking for a vanilla CSS method so far.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is impossible with just CSS, you could however add JavaScript to dynamically add a class to all elements that have `data-*` attrinutes. Just out of curiosity: why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Zero21xxx I don't think a preprocessor would help here, because a preprocessor ultimately doesn't extend the capabilities of CSS, it just makes writing it easier. There is in infinite number of possible `data` attributes, so you can't specify them all, unless you know exactly which ones may occur.

Comment: Yea, I haven't found any vanilla CSS solution yet...I don't have a particular use case. I'm working through learning CSS selectors right now and got a little tripped up on whether or not this is possible.

Comment: Yeah I was just wondering if there was a finite numbers of these so you could write some sort of CSS function or mix-in. But you're right, that would only help if there was a finite list.

Comment: Actually, can you clarify if you are looking for all elements that have `data` specifically (as an attribute)? Or that *contain* `data` *as part of a longer/larger attribute name*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no wildcarding for attribute names in CSS selectors. All [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) contain a specific name of an attribute.

Comment: Because the original question requires the wildcard to work on the attribute itself. For instance, a CSS rule that aims to style all attributes that begin with [custom-*] - where the asterisk (*) represents the wildcard. This is not possible.

Comment: Who else imagined for sure they'd done this before and is now very disappointed!

Answer (score 37):

As you have pointed out, there are multiple ways to target the *value* of an HTML attribute.

> - E[foo="bar"]
>
>   *an E element whose "foo" attribute value is exactly*
>     equal to "bar"
>
> ---
>
> - E[foo~="bar"]
>
>   *an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar"*
>
> ---
>
> - E[foo^="bar"]
>
>   *an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"*
>
> ---
>
> - E[foo$="bar"]
>
>   *an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar"*
>
> ---
>
> - E[foo*="bar"]
>
>   *an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar"*
>
> ---
>
> - E[foo|="en"]
>
>   *an E element whose "foo" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "en"*

**But there is only one way to target the attribute name itself:**

> - E[foo]
>
>   *an E element with a "foo" attribute*

Hence, there are currently no methods for wildcarding attribute names:

```
div[data-*] { ... } /* may be useful, but doesn't exist */
div[data-^] { ... } /* may be useful, but doesn't exist */
```

<sub>source: [W3C Selectors Level 3 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)</sub>

---

From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877416/3597276) to a similar question:

> There is a recent
>   [thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0069.html)
>   in the www-style@w3.org mailing list, where Simon Pieters from Opera
>   has proposed a nice possible
>   [syntax](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0114.html)
>   that has got some acceptance in the thread, so there is a chance that
>   it will become standard somewhen in the future:
>
> ```css
> x-admin-* { ... }
> [data-my-*] { ... }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For the data- attribute there is the attribute 'data-set' which contains a list of all data-* attributes in a single string. Acting on it with the existing wildcard operators MIGHT be solution:

```
[data-set*="bar:"]
```

would select an element with the data-bar attribute (even with an empty value!), but also if there is a data-foobar attribute (the ':' is there to ensure it is an attribute name, not an attribute value)

Answer (score -7):

YES, you can select all elements that have any value of a specified attribute:

[`type] selects all elements that have a type="anything" attribute`

Comment: It's rightly downvoted because it is not answering the question about wildcard attribute name.