# Universal CSS selector to match any and all HTML data-* attributes

Tags: css, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to match all nodes that have a `data-*` attribute using **only** CSS?

Here are examples of attributes I would like to match:

```
data-scope
data-sessionlink
data-visibility-tracking
```

I could do

```
*[data-scope] *[data-sessionlink] *[data-visibility-tracking]
```

but I am looking for something more compact. Furthermore, I don't know all possible `data-*` attributes I might encounter in my application.

Comment: Are these attributes or attribute values (e.g. Class="data-scope")

Comment: These are attributes.

Comment: Dang. There's a wildcard search for attribute values starting with a string, but not, as far as I know, attributes.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the wildcard attribute value selector, and I am not holding out much hope that what I would like to do is possible, but you never know until you ask others.

Comment: I'm not certain this is possible without the use of javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currenly impossible to use wildcard masks to select elements by an attribute-name part.

There is a recent [thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0069.html) in the www-style@w3.org mailing list, where Simon Pieters from Opera has proposed a nice possible [syntax](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0114.html) that has got some acceptance in the thread, so there is a chance that it will become standard somewhen in the future:

```css
x-admin-* { ... }
[data-my-*] { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, Marat! I hope that one day we will be able to do wildcard selection on attribute names.

Comment: Not the greatest idea though - won't allow you to do [data-my-*='exact match'] because *= clashes with an existing operator

Comment: @gotofritz Good point. But this could probably be resolved by wrapping the attribute name itself in quotes: `["data-my-*" = "exact match"]`