# Find Custom Elements that start with a specified prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-element

I have a bunch of Custom Elements that begin with 'food-cta-'. I am looking for a way in JavaScript/jQuery to be able to select these elements. This is similar to how I can use `$('*[class^="food-cta-"]')` to select all the classes that start with `food-cta-`. Is it possible to do a search for elements that start with 'food-cta-'?

Note that I will be injecting this search onto the page, so I won't have access to Angular.

Example of Custom Elements:

- `<food-cta-download>`
- `<food-cta-external>`
- `<food-cta-internal>`

EDIT: The code I am looking at looks like:

```
<food-cta-download type="primary" description="Download Recipe">
    <img src="">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
</food-cta-download>
```

The app uses AngularJS to create Custom Elements which I believe is called Directives.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, [they're custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements), which is a newer standard for HTML.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, or it's a [custom html element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) which will inherit from [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) or [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement) if not registered

Comment: You can add in the link function of each directive `element.addClass('food-cta')` and then all the elements with those directive will have the same class, but AFAIK you can't select element this way as you do with class - You have to list the elements `food-cta-download, food-cta-external, food-cta-internal {background:red;}`

Comment: @AlonEitan Unfortunately I am unable to change any of the Angular code otherwise that would have been a wonderful solution!

Comment: Do you already have a list of all the possible tag names it could use?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Unfortunately I do not. In addition, the list may grow overtime which is why I am looking for a dynamic solution.

Comment: @Jon Can you copy the element after it was altered by the directive and add it to the question? Maybe the directives add some class or change the structure of the elements to something you can then select using a unified selector in css

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36877416) about wildcard selector for attributes that is also applicable to tag-name wildcard selectors. TLDR: that's currently impossible, but there is a proposal that has some acceptance and will probably specced/implemented in the future.

Comment: I don't believe that these are [Angular Directives](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp). Angular Directives are custom attributes, not Custom Elements. They sit on regular HTML5 elements with the `ng-` prefix/namespace.

Comment: @Jon if you want a direct extension of jquery, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) with the expression

```
 //*[starts-with(name(),'food-cta-')]
```

Where

- `//*` is wildcard for all nodes
- [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) is a XPath function to test a string starts with some value
- [`name()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/name) gets the QName (node name)
- and `'food-cta-'` is the search term

Pass it into [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) and you will get a [XPathResult](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult) that will give you the nodes that were matched.

```
var result = document.evaluate( "//*[starts-with(name(),'food-cta-')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

Note you can use any node as the root, you do not need to use `document`. So you could for instance replace `document` with the some div:

```
var container = document.getElementById("#container");
var result = document.evaluate( "//*[starts-with(name(),'food-cta-')]", container, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

Demo

```js
let result = document.evaluate( "//*[starts-with(name(),'food-cta-')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );

let nodes = [];
let anode = null;

while( (anode = result.iterateNext()) ){
   nodes.push( anode.nodeName );
}

console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <br>
  <food-cta-download type="primary" description="Download Recipe">
    <img src="">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </food-cta-download>
  <span>Some span</span>
  <food-cta-something>
    <img src="">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </food-cta-something>
  <div>In between
      <food-cta-sub>
         <img src="">
         <h2></h2>
         <p></p>
      </food-cta-sub>
  </div>
  <food-cta-hello>
    <img src="">
  </food-cta-hello>
  <food-cta-whattt>
  </food-cta-whattt>
</div>
```

Comment: It's clever and I like it, but the question did specifically call for JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, that is javascript, hence why you can run it in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to just go to the elements in question and check if their tagName begins with that given string...

```
var myPrefix = "mycustom-thing-";

$("body").children().each(function() {
  if (this.tagName.substr(0, myPrefix.length).toLowerCase() == myPrefix) {
    console.log(this.innerHTML); // or what ever 
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/duLo2d0z/

**EDIT: Included for efficiency's sake:**

If you can predict where the elements will be, you can of course specify that circumstance.
In my example, the elements in question were direct children of `body` - so I could use `.children()` to get them. This would not traverse lower levels.

Reduce the need for traversal by the following:

Start on the lowest needed level (`$("#specific-id")` rather than `$("body")`)

If the elements are all to be found **as direct children** of a container:

- Use `$.children()` on the container to obtain just the immediate children

Else

- Use `$.find("*")`

If you can tell something about the containing context, filter by that

For example `$("#specific-id").find(".certain-container-class .child-class *")`

Comment: This seems like a very expensive call as it will have to traverse pretty much the entire DOM.

Comment: So you have to use `.find()` instead? ...Well, in a way, jQ would have to do that anyway if it were a check for a class or something else natively supported. But yes, I get that and of course I too wish it were supported

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize `$.find()` traverses the entire DOM as well. Lol. I thought it did some sneaky algorithm thing that saves performance.

Comment: What do you mean? `.find("*")` will check every children in any level, `.children()` will only check the first level. __If__ there was a top-level tagName selector, we could filter the `.find()` call and jQ could take full advantage of its speedy algorithms. Now, as it stands, we have to retrieve an object for every element and then check for its tagName, which is more expensive

Comment: You could improve performance by giving the selector more specificity, for example, if you know the content is going to be inside a specific content area.  It would traverse less of the DOM.

Comment: @heart.cooks.mind Of course. In my fiddle, I used `children()` and `body` was the direct parent so I didn't think to include that in my answer... will do

Comment: Updated the answer to that regard

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
let customElements = $('*')
  .filter((index,element) => /FOOD-CTI-/.test(element.tagName));
```

Note, `.tagName` should return the result in uppercase. This should get you a jQuery object of the elements you want. It will traverse the entire DOM though. It'll be slow.

This uses the [*"all selector"*](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/).

> Caution: The all, or universal, selector is extremely slow, except when used by itself.

You can traverse less then entire dom too, by specifying something like `$("body *")`. Not sure where you have put the Custom Elements, and where they're allowed.

As an aside, I wouldn't use Custom Elements, microformats are a better idea at least now, they're also better supported, and they're less likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

Why not [extend jquery selectors](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki)?

```
$(':tag(^=food-cta-)')
```

Would be possible with the following implementation:

```js
$.expr[':'].tag = function tag(element, index, match) {
  // prepare dummy attribute
  // avoid string processing when possible by using element.localName
  // instead of element.tagName.toLowerCase()
  tag.$.attr('data-tag', element.localName || element.tagName.toLowerCase());
  // in :tag(`pattern`), match[3] = `pattern`
  var pattern = tag.re.exec(match[3]);
  // [data-tag`m`="`pattern`"]
  var selector = '[data-tag' + (pattern[1] || '') + '="' + pattern[2] + '"]';
  // test if custom tag selector matches element
  // using dummy attribute polyfill
  return tag.$.is(selector);
};

// dummy element to run attribute selectors on
$.expr[':'].tag.$ = $('<div/>');
// cache RegExp for parsing ":tag(m=pattern)"
$.expr[':'].tag.re = /^(?:([~\|\^\$\*])?=)?(.*)$/;

// some tests
console.log('^=food-cta-', $(':tag(^=food-cta-)').toArray());
console.log('*=cta-s', $(':tag(*=cta-s)').toArray());
console.log('food-cta-hello', $(':tag(food-cta-hello)').toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <br>
  <food-cta-download type="primary" description="Download Recipe">
    <img src="">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </food-cta-download>
  <span>Some span</span>
  <food-cta-something>
    <img src="">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
  </food-cta-something>
  <div>In between
    <food-cta-sub>
      <img src="">
      <h2></h2>
      <p></p>
    </food-cta-sub>
  </div>
  <food-cta-hello>
    <img src="">
  </food-cta-hello>
  <food-cta-whattt>
  </food-cta-whattt>
</div>
```

This supports a pseudo-CSS-style [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with the syntax:

```
:tag(m=pattern)
```

Or just

```
:tag(pattern)
```

where `m` is `~,|,^,$,*` and `pattern` is your tag selector.