# CSS - attribute starts with selector?

Tags: css

I have HTML markup that contain randomly generated attributes from Angular. For example,

`<i _ngcontent-sgg-c2 class="some-class"></i>`

These attributes do not have values so I'm wondering in this case if I can use the [attribute^=value] attribute selector. Am I able to apply styles to all elements where the attributes themselves start with a certain pattern?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: You could probably achieve this with `javascript`, by finding all elements that start with a certain attribute a class, and then target that class with `css`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use wildcards on attributes names. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21222776/3980303 where it was originally answered.

It seems though that the generated attribute of Angular is used for scoped styles.
Check this link for reference it explains that good https://dev.to/themeticulist/everything-you-should-know-about-styles-in-angular-12ab

Cheers.