# How to exclude element with attribute from selector regardless of value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm working a framework that create on screen certain elements that should not be modified in any way, at all, ever, under any circumstances . These elements always have a data-for attribute with some value.

I know I could exclude them from a selector by using not command like:

```
 input:not([data-for], .exclude)
```

In case of having a value I know I could do something like

```
input:not([data-for=lalala], .exclude)
```

The problem is that I won't know the value at development time and the first option only works when the attribute has no value. Is there another to do this?

Comment: I bet on input:not([data-for]) too, it selects all input that havent data-for attr not matter value
https://jsfiddle.net/willystyle/08wnerv5/16/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21222375/3597276

Comment: It should work, for some reason it does not. I'm gonna test again tomorrow when I get back to work. Maybe it is something I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input:not[data-for]` selector should work. See below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($('input[data-for]').length);
  console.log($('input:not([data-for])').length);
});
```

```css
input{ display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-for="" />
<input data-for="something" />
<input />
<input />
<input data-for="something" />
<input data-for="" />
```

Comment: It should work, for some reason it does not. I'm gonna test again tomorrow when I get back to work. Maybe it is something I missed.

Comment: After a lot of checking I've found out that the framework had other hidden inputs which shouldn't be changed. So the data-for is only part of the issue.
I'm going to mark your anwser as correct because it does solve the problem that I've posted, even though, unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem :(.
Thanks anyways for the help.

Comment: @PauloKünzel No problem, and post again if you have issues