# style auto generated html attributes with regex

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an ionic/angular app which autogenerates a custom `tag` element with a different `_ngcontent` attribute each time e.g.:

```
<tag _ngcontent-hgr-c2>...</tag> (1st refresh)
<tag _ngcontent-agj-c7>...</tag> (2nd refresh)
<tag _ngcontent-cfx-c5>...</tag> (3rd refresh)
```

Is there a way to use regex to target the custom tag attribute?

This didn't work:

```
tag[^=_ngcontent-] {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Nor did just targetting the tag app e.g.:

```
tag {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: `\b_ngcontent-\w\w\w-\w\d\b` - Does this work for you ?

Comment: @rootkonda no - I think I need to approach this in a different way. Thanks for the regex above though, it was correct in itself, just not for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8903451) answer, there is kind of regex in CSS, but it can be only applied to attribute's value, not to attribute itself. The [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview) says the same, so because Angular creates custom attributes, I'm afraid that it can be hard to achieve by regex.

If you want to style your `tag` like in the second example you can do it by defining its styles in global `styles.scss`. This is not the best solution, but should work.

This [angular-blog article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) recently helped me understand the idea behind the style ecapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no wildcarding support in CSS for attribute *names*.

If you have access to the application code which generates the custom tags, you should add classes to these elements (if the app supports it).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222375/css-selector-for-attribute-names-based-on-a-wildcard).