# Is there a way to target an element with dynamic property name?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML structure looks like this. Some of the element has a dynamic attribute name starts with `data-ref-` followed by some random hex code.

Is there away to target the attribute name partically?

```css
[data-ref-*='group'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-ref-15af36e1="group">foo</div>
<div data-ref-63b361af="group">bar</div>
<div data-ref-c836eea7="item">baz</div>
```

In this example I want the `foo` and `bar` to be red. Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way (as yet) to specify a CSS selector with a wildcard for an attribute name, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222375/css-selector-for-attribute-names-based-on-a-wildcard

Answer (score 1):

Although CSS Attribute Selectors cannot do the desired, you can use [Document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) and [XPATH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) to query the elements and set the style:

```
//*[@*[starts-with(name(), "data-ref-")]="group"]
```

```js
var matchingElements = document.evaluate(
  '//*[@*[starts-with(name(), "data-ref-")]="group"]',
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
  null
);

while (matchingElement = matchingElements.iterateNext()) {
  matchingElement.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<div data-ref-15af36e1="group">foo</div>
<div data-ref-63b361af="group">bar</div>
<div data-ref-c836eea7="item">baz</div>
```